# Failed lookup for key [page] in u"[{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {}, {}]"

Tags: python, django, templates, exception

When I try to navigate to a page, which uses this article function view in my news/views.py file, it is coming up with this error. I tried debugging the view, and it seems the template, and context are both good, so I am not sure why this is happening.

news/views.py

```
def article(request, a_slug):
    a_slug = a_slug.strip('/')

    articles = Article.objects.get(slug=a_slug)
    recent = Article.objects.all()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewsForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            cleaned_data = NewsForm.cleaned_data

    else:
        form = NewsForm()

    context = {'article': articles, 'recent': recent, 'form': form}
    set_detail_context(request, context)

    template = "overrides/news.html"

    return render_to_response(template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

news/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^article/(?P<a_slug>.*)/?$', views.article, name='article')
]
```

news/html.py

```
{% for article in articles %}
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 article">
                            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="article-image" style="background-image: url('{{ article.image }}');"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12" id="content">
                                <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
                                <p>{{ article.story|slice:"180" }}</p>
                                <a href="article/{{ article.slug }}">
                                    <button class="article-btn">
                                        READ MORE
                                    </button>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

Django source code where exception was raised

```
current = context
        try:  # catch-all for silent variable failures
            for bit in self.lookups:
                try:  # dictionary lookup
                    current = current[bit]
                    # ValueError/IndexError are for numpy.array lookup on
                    # numpy < 1.9 and 1.9+ respectively
                except (TypeError, AttributeError, KeyError, ValueError, IndexError):
                    try:  # attribute lookup
                        # Don't return class attributes if the class is the context:
                        if isinstance(current, BaseContext) and getattr(type(current), bit):
                            raise AttributeError
                        current = getattr(current, bit)
                    except (TypeError, AttributeError) as e:
                        # Reraise an AttributeError raised by a @property
                        if (isinstance(e, AttributeError) and
                                not isinstance(current, BaseContext) and bit in dir(current)):
                            raise
                        try:  # list-index lookup
                            current = current[int(bit)]
                        except (IndexError,  # list index out of range
                                ValueError,  # invalid literal for int()
                                KeyError,    # current is a dict without `int(bit)` key
                                TypeError):  # unsubscriptable object
                            raise VariableDoesNotExist("Failed lookup for key "
                                                       "[%s] in %r",
                                                       (bit, current))  # missing attribute
```

Stacktrace:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/news/article/atlas-featured-in-retailing-today/

Django Version: 1.9.1
Python Version: 2.7.11
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'filebrowser',
 'suit',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'reversion',
 'classytags',
 'mptt',
 'inplaceeditform',
 'inplaceeditform_extra_fields',
 'contact',
 'home_content',
 'navigation',
 'page_content',
 'webapp',
 'webapp_admin',
 'testimonials',
 'products',
 'services',
 'news',
 'clients',
 'staff',
 'careers')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /Users/timothybaney/Django_Projects/Atlas_Technology_Web/templates/overrides/news.html, error at line 0
   (Could not get exception message)   1 : {% extends 'detail_page.html' %}
   2 : {% load inplace_edit %}
   3 : {% load static %}
   4 : 
   5 : {% block extra-head %}
   6 :     {{ block.super }}
   7 :     <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='/static/css/news.css'>
   8 : {% endblock %}
   9 : 
   10 : 


Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/timothybaney/Django_Projects/Atlas_Technology_Web/news/views.py" in article
  55.     return render_to_response(template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render_to_response
  45.             using=using)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  114.                         template_name, context, context_instance, dirs, dictionary)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py" in render_to_string
  244.             return t.render(context_instance)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  206.                     return self._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  988.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  955.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  173.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  988.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  955.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  173.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  988.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  955.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  69.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  988.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  955.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  69.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  988.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  955.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/timothybaney/Django_Projects/Atlas_Technology_Web/inplaceeditform/tag_utils.py" in render
  104.         context = self.prepare_context(args, kwargs, context)

File "/Users/timothybaney/Django_Projects/Atlas_Technology_Web/inplaceeditform/templatetags/inplace_edit.py" in prepare_context
  99.         obj = Variable(obj_context).resolve(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  846.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  901.                                                        (bit, current))  # missing attribute

Exception Type: VariableDoesNotExist at /news/article/atlas-featured-in-retailing-today/
Exception Value: Failed lookup for key [page] in u"[{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {}, {}]"
```

inplace_edit.py

```
register = Library()


def inplace_js(context, activate_inplaceedit=True, toolbar=False):
    request = context['request']
    request.inplace_js_rendered = True
    return {
        'STATIC_URL': get_static_url(),
        'ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX': get_admin_static_url(),
        'activate_inplaceedit': activate_inplaceedit,
        'auto_save': json.dumps(inplace_settings.INPLACEEDIT_AUTO_SAVE),
        'event': inplace_settings.INPLACEEDIT_EVENT,
        'disable_click': json.dumps(inplace_settings.INPLACEEDIT_DISABLE_CLICK),
        'toolbar': toolbar,
        'enable_class': inplace_settings.INPLACE_ENABLE_CLASS,
        'success_text': inplace_settings.INPLACEEDIT_SUCCESS_TEXT,
        'unsaved_changes': inplace_settings.INPLACEEDIT_UNSAVED_TEXT,
        'inplace_get_field_url': inplace_settings.INPLACE_GET_FIELD_URL or reverse('inplace_get_field'),
        'inplace_save_url': inplace_settings.INPLACE_SAVE_URL or reverse('inplace_save'),
        'field_types': inplace_settings.INPLACE_FIELD_TYPES,
        'focus_when_editing': json.dumps(inplace_settings.INPLACE_FOCUS_WHEN_EDITING),
        'inplace_js_extra': getattr(request, 'inplace_js_extra', '')
    }
register.inclusion_tag("inplaceeditform/inplace_js.html", takes_context=True)(inplace_js)


def inplace_css(context, toolbar=False):
    request = context['request']
    request.inplace_css_rendered = True
    return {
        'STATIC_URL': get_static_url(),
        'ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX': get_admin_static_url(),
        'toolbar': toolbar,
        'inplace_js_extra': getattr(request, 'inplace_css_extra', '')
    }
register.inclusion_tag("inplaceeditform/inplace_css.html", takes_context=True)(inplace_css)


def inplace_static(context):
    return {
        'STATIC_URL': get_static_url(),
        'ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX': get_admin_static_url(),
        'toolbar': False,
        'request': context['request']
    }
register.inclusion_tag("inplaceeditform/inplace_static.html", takes_context=True)(inplace_static)


#to old django versions
def inplace_media(context):
    return inplace_static(context)
register.inclusion_tag("inplaceeditform/inplace_static.html", takes_context=True)(inplace_media)


def inplace_toolbar(context):
    return {
        'STATIC_URL': get_static_url(),
        'ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX': get_admin_static_url(),
        'toolbar': True,
        'request': context['request']
    }
register.inclusion_tag("inplaceeditform/inplace_static.html", takes_context=True)(inplace_toolbar)


class InplaceEditNode(RenderWithArgsAndKwargsNode):

    def prepare_context(self, args, kwargs, context):
        expression_to_show = args[0]
        tokens_to_show = expression_to_show.split('|')
        obj_field_name, filters_to_show = tokens_to_show[0], '|'.join(tokens_to_show[1:])
        obj_field_name_split = obj_field_name.split(".")
        obj_context = '.'.join(obj_field_name_split[:-1])
        field_name = obj_field_name_split[-1]
        obj = Variable(obj_context).resolve(context)
        adaptor = kwargs.get('adaptor', None)
        class_adaptor = get_adaptor_class(adaptor, obj, field_name)
        request = context.get('request')

        config = class_adaptor.get_config(request, **kwargs)

        adaptor_field = class_adaptor(request, obj, field_name,
                                      filters_to_show,
                                      config)

        context = {
            'adaptor_field': adaptor_field,
        }
        return context


@register.tag
def inplace_edit(parser, token):
    args, kwargs = parse_args_kwargs(parser, token)
    return InplaceEditNode(args, kwargs, 'inplaceeditform/inplace_edit.html')


@register.tag(name='eval')
def do_eval(parser, token):
    "Usage: {% eval %}1 + 1{% endeval %}"

    nodelist = parser.parse(('endeval',))

    class EvalNode(template.Node):
        def render(self, context):
            return template.Template(nodelist.render(context)).render(template.Context(context))
    parser.delete_first_token()
    return EvalNode()
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: yep edited my original question to post it for you.

Comment: Can you also post detail_page.html in which the error occurs...

Comment: I don't think that the error is happening on detail_page.html, there was simply not a newline for 1 : {% extends 'detail_page.html' %} which is part of  news.html.

Comment: The error seems to be cause by line 99 in File "/Users/timothybaney/Django_Projects/Atlas_Technology_Web/inplaceeditform/templatetags/inplace_edit.py" in prepare_context
  `99.         obj = Variable(obj_context).resolve(context)`.  Can you post the inplace_edit.py file?

Comment: yeah, I put it at the bottom of the original question.

Comment: Can you do a quick check by removing the line `{% load inplace_edit %}` from `news.html` to see if error goes away or changes? Hint: change the '%` to `#` to make it a comment but leave it in place.

Comment: I don't see any use of `inplace_edit` tags within `news.html` such as: `{% inplace_edit  "OBJ.FIELD_NAME" %}`. It is used anywhere in the template hierarchy for this request?